# Python Database Pooling with psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

Below is a database pooling example. I don't understand the following.

1. Why the getcursor function use "yield"?
2. What is the context manager?

   ```
   from psycopg2.pool import SimpleConnectionPool
   from contextlib import contextmanager

   dbConnection = "dbname='dbname' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='postgres'"

   # pool define with 10 live connections
   connectionpool = SimpleConnectionPool(1,10,dsn=dbConnection)

   @contextmanager
   def getcursor():
       con = connectionpool.getconn()
       try:
           yield con.cursor()
       finally:
           connectionpool.putconn(con)

   def main_work():
       try:
           # with here will take care of put connection when its done
           with getcursor() as cur:
               cur.execute("select * from \"TableName\"")
               result_set = cur.fetchall()

       except Exception as e:
           print "error in executing with exception: ", e**
   ```

Comment: `yield` lets you work with records sooner, than you having to wait for the whole list to be built.  Context manager makes is so that, whenever you leave that identation, the connection automatically closes.

Answer (score 3):

Both of your questions are related.  In python context managers are what we're using whenever you see a `with` statement.  Classically, they're written like this.

```
class getcursor(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        con = connectionpool.getconn()
        return con

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        connectionpool.putconn(con)
```

Now when you use a context manager, it calls the `__enter__` method on the `with` statement and the `__exit__` method when it exits the context.  Think of it like this.

```
cursor = getcursor()
with cursor as cur: # calls cursor.__enter__()
   cur.execute("select * from \"TableName\"")
   result_set = cur.fetchall()
# We're now exiting the context so it calls `cursor.__exit__()` 
# with some exception info if relevant
x = 1
```

The `@contextmanager` decorator is some sugar to make creating a context manager easier.  Basically, it uses the `yield` statement to give the execution back to the caller.  Everything up to and including the `yield` statement is the `__enter__` method and everything after that is effectively the `__exit__` statement.